# Locating a color in an array in c

Tags: c, colors, coordinates, locate

```
int locate_color(  const uint8_t array[], 
           unsigned int cols, 
           unsigned int rows,
           uint8_t color,
           unsigned int *x,
           unsigned int *y )
{
    for (int z = 0; z < rows; z++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        { 
            if (array[z] == color)
            {
                *x = color;
            }
            if (array[c] == color)
            {
                *y = color;
            }
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function is a function that locates a color from an array.  It searches from left to right and top to bottom, and when it is found, it stores the coordinates into the *x and *y.  But when I ran the code, it gave me an error.  Would anyone be able to tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't describe the problem. You should better set it, for example to: *got an `error <type>` in a loop*, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

- You need to access the array elements differently, something like:

  ```
  if (*(array + z * cols + c) == color)
  ```

  That will offset the pointer `array` decays to by `z` (the row index) times the length of a row, plus `c` (the column index), then dereference it to get the element there to compare against `color`.
- You need to set `*x` and `*y` to the row (`z`) and column (`c`) you found the color in, not to the color itself.
- You're missing a brace (`}`) at the end of your inner `for` loop
- You only need one `if` to check that you've found the color, within which you can set both the `x` and `y` coordinates

Assuming no extra padding at the end of each row, and that each pixel is 8 bits, the contents of your inner for loop would be:

```
        if (*(array + z * cols + c) == color)
        {
            *x = c;
            *y = z;
            return 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

const uint8_t array is a one dimension array. I believe you expect a two dimension array which is like:

```
array[z][c];

for (int z = 0; z < rows; z++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    { 
        if (array[z][c] == color)
        {
            *x = color;
            *y = color;
            return 1;   // return 1 only if you find the matching color.
        }  
    }
}
```